# D3v5 Custom Bundle

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to follow the [v4 custom bundle instructions](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/bb09af4c39c79cffcde4) with D3js v5.

Is there another set of instructions for building specific bundles for v5?  "prepublish" isn't listed in the script section for the v5 package.json.

Edit 2018-12-12:
So searching through the scripts section, I ran these commands to get D3 V5.7.0 to build:

`git clone https://github.com/d3/d3.git

cd d3

npm install

npm run pretest

npm run test

npm run prepublishOnly`

I had about 20 errors like this, but still ended up with a d3.js and d3.min.js file to use:
`(!) Circular dependency: node_modules/d3-selection/src/selection/index.js -> node_modules/d3-selection/src/selection/select.js -> node_modules/d3-selection/src/selection/index.js`

Comment: Since that's the custom bundle's package.json you can basically name the script anything that comes to mind; it's not necessarily `prepublish`. Alternatively, like mentioned by Mike Bostock in his instructions, you can just run rollup from the command line.

Comment: Thank you-that makes sense.